# SAFE-stack with github authorization

Tags: oauth, f#, fable-f#, saturn-framework, safe-stack

I am trying to hide my whole application behind a authentication (I'll deal with authorization when this works), and for now I want to every url to require github login. I am not getting the github login page up.

I have tried to combine the [SAFE-stack template](https://safe-stack.github.io/docs/quickstart/) and ["Using OAuth with Saturn"](https://medium.com/lambda-factory/using-oauth-with-saturn-c8eba5d63e1c), but I do not get the github login page (which I do get when following only the Saturn guide), I just get the normal todo page. If I click the Add button, the server prints

```
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics[1]
      Request starting HTTP/1.1 POST http://localhost:8085/api/ITodosApi/addTodo application/json; charset=UTF-8 68
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OAuth.OAuthHandler`1[[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OAuth.OAuthOptions, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OAuth, Version=3.1.11.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60]][12]
      AuthenticationScheme: GitHub was challenged.
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics[2]
      Request finished in 10.8057ms 302
```

And the item is not added to the list of todos.

I have tried shaving off everything except the authentication bit, and compared to a clean safe template, the only changes I have made is

1. `dotnet paket add Saturn.Extensions.Authorization --project src/Server/Server.fsproj`
2. Manually downgrade two dependencies in `paket.lock` that otherwise created an error: `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Google` to `(3.1.11)` and     `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect` to `(3.1.11)`
3. Change the `app` value in `Server/Server.fs` to the following (I created a new github auth app for this issue):

```
let loggedInPipeline = pipeline {
    requires_authentication (Giraffe.Auth.challenge "GitHub")
}

let loggedInView = router {
    pipe_through loggedInPipeline
    get "/" webApp
}

let appRouter = router {
    forward "" loggedInView
}

let app =
    application {
        use_router appRouter
        url "http://0.0.0.0:8085/"
        memory_cache
        use_static "public"
        use_gzip
        use_github_oauth "8cde657dfd1d3a41b9ed" "0b245e12900ff8486ade076aae07aa0deb0fd83d" "/signin-github" [("login", "githubUsername"); ("name", "fullName")]
    }

run app
```

My gitHub app config auth callback url: `http://localhost:8080/signin-github`

Comment: You can get the whole repo here: https://github.com/EspenBrun/safe-with-github

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got help on solving this, just for AzureAD. A blog post can be found here https://www.compositional-it.com/news-blog/safe-stack-authentication-with-active-directory-part-2/. Should be the same for github. What I needed to do was to make some changes to `webpack.config.js`, `Server.fs` and `build.fsx`

**webpack.config.js**

```js
devServerProxy: {
    // redirect all requests to the server on port 8085
    '**': {
//...
```

```js
var CONFIG = {
    appHtmlTemplate: './src/Client/app.html',
//...
```

```js
var commonPlugins = [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        filename: 'app.html',
//...
```

```js
var CONFIG = {
    // ... other webpack config settings
    outputDir: './src/Server/public',
     // ...
```

```js
    devServer: {
        // ...other dev server config settings
        writeToDisk: true
    },
```

**`Server.fs`:**

```ml
let authScheme = "AzureAD"

let isDevelopment = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT") = Environments.Development;

let noAuthenticationRequired nxt ctx = task { return! nxt ctx }

let authChallenge : HttpFunc -> HttpContext -> HttpFuncResult =
    requiresAuthentication (Auth.challenge authScheme)

let routes =
    choose [
        route "/" >=> authChallenge >=>  htmlFile "public/app.html"
    ]
```

**build.fsx:**

```ml
let serverPublicPath = Path.getFullName "./src/Server/public"
let clientPublicPath = Path.getFullName "./src/Client/public"
```

```ml
Target.create "Clean" (fun _ ->
    Shell.cleanDir deployDir
    Shell.cleanDir serverPublicPath)
```

```ml
Target.create "Run" (fun _ ->
    Shell.copyDir serverPublicPath clientPublicPath FileFilter.allFiles
    //... other commands
```

You will need to use a non-Chrome browser if you are working locally, such as Firefox, due to the cookie issue mentioned earlier.

It is a good idea to open a private browsing window, to make sure that you don't already have a logged in account etc.

If you are having issues, check that you have

- properly set up your app's Active Directory registration in Azure
- added the required AD configuration to your Server in `appsettings.json`, including the login / logout callback urls you set in the AD registration.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried `https` instead of `http` for your `url` parameter?

Replace

```
url "http://0.0.0.0:8085"
```

with

```
url "https://0.0.0.0:8085"
```

This fixed the problem for me.

Demo code: https://github.com/functionalfriday/fsharp-saturn-demos

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I tried to change the url parameter to https, and also in the webpack.config.js file for the dev server proxy. I can not find any other places referring to http, but it still tries to request `GET http://localhost:8080/api/ITodosApi/getTodos`, which now returns a 500 error.

Comment: Have you also changed the callback URL in the Github settings to use `https`?
The "Authorization callback URL" ***within "Github" -> "OAuth Apps"***?
For my demo app referenced above, the value used in Github is `https://localhost:5000/signin-github`

Comment: I could not solve this in the way you suggested, but I ended up getting a way to do it with AzureAD from one of the SAFE-stack maintainers. Thanks for taking the time to suggest answers!